# How to build a Mac M1 arm64 image from an existing docker repository

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, arm64, buildx

I'm trying to run a docker [elasticsearch:2.3.4](https://hub.docker.com/layers/travelspells/elasticsearch-2.3.4/latest/images/sha256-6be5666f7cbe7d89b178d2ecf10d2befcaee445ed3480995b93fd95542db981e?context=explore) container on a Mac M1. But the container fails because that image supports only `linux/amd64`. In contrast to the latest image, [ElasticSearch:8.5.1](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/elasticsearch/8.5.1/images/sha256-99571e76b4ba7719366bb41e21794edfc8419c0b5cf63e318203a34e5b5db7b7?context=explore), supports `linux/amd64` and `linux/arm64/v8`.

For legacy reasons I still require the `2.3.4` version of ES. With this in mind I tried to build a ES 2.3.4 image with support for arm64 following [these instructions](https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-rapidly-build-multi-architecture-images-with-buildx/). However I believe my inexperience with this is showing. The approach I took was to create a `Dockerfile` with

```
FROM elasticsearch:2.3.4
```

as the only instruction. My hope being that this would magically work. Instead when I run

> docker buildx build --push --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 --tag myrepo/elasticsearch:2.3.4 .

It produces the following error

```
[+] Building 4.0s (6/6) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
=> [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
=> => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
=> => transferring dockerfile: 61B                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
=> [linux/amd64 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/elasticsearch:2.3.4                                                                                                                                                                     3.9s
=> [linux/arm64 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/elasticsearch:2.3.4                                                                                                                                                                     3.9s
=> ERROR [linux/arm64 1/1] FROM docker.io/library/elasticsearch:2.3.4@sha256:7a09f0b9204b0e331eb7031bf30e12c8138c53c61938d59bb07b9a1c6de93483                                                                                                         0.0s
=> => resolve docker.io/library/elasticsearch:2.3.4@sha256:7a09f0b9204b0e331eb7031bf30e12c8138c53c61938d59bb07b9a1c6de93483                                                                                                                           0.0s
=> ERROR [linux/amd64 1/1] FROM docker.io/library/elasticsearch:2.3.4@sha256:7a09f0b9204b0e331eb7031bf30e12c8138c53c61938d59bb07b9a1c6de93483                                                                                                         0.0s
=> => resolve docker.io/library/elasticsearch:2.3.4@sha256:7a09f0b9204b0e331eb7031bf30e12c8138c53c61938d59bb07b9a1c6de93483                                                                                                                           0.0s
------
 > [linux/arm64 1/1] FROM docker.io/library/elasticsearch:2.3.4@sha256:7a09f0b9204b0e331eb7031bf30e12c8138c53c61938d59bb07b9a1c6de93483:
------
------
> [linux/amd64 1/1] FROM docker.io/library/elasticsearch:2.3.4@sha256:7a09f0b9204b0e331eb7031bf30e12c8138c53c61938d59bb07b9a1c6de93483:
------
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM elasticsearch:2.3.4
--------------------
error: failed to solve: failed to load cache key: content digest : not found
```

For which I've found little to no information.

Any thoughts on what's the best approach here? Do I instead need to rebuild the `elasticsearch:2.3.4` image from scratch? What's the approach taken to migrating an existing image to arm64?

Comment: You can't start FROM an Intel image to create an arm one as output. Yes, you should rebuild it.

Comment: (also, good luck; while arm64 in general was around, ES2 is from before the Apple M1 existed; hopefully it's still able to run in newer JVMs)

Comment: That certainly changes the "profile" of my problem. Looks like I could maybe base it off https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/main/distribution/docker/src/docker/Dockerfile. But that was first uploaded in 2018. ES2.3.4 was released in 2016. I suspect I may need to drop this, as it's got to have legs.